# Lambda function inside DataFrame Apply

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply

I have the following DataFrame in Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 1, 1, 0),
                   (2, 0, 0, 2),
                   (3, 0, 1, 3),
                   (4, 5, 3, 0)],
                  columns=list('abcd'))
```

I need to implement the following function into that DataFrame:

[image]

I'm trying to use the `apply()` function below:

```
dfs = df.apply(lambda x: np.mean(x)+2*np.std(x) if x > np.mean(x)+2*np.std(x) else x, axis = 0, result_type='broadcast')
dfs
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Not really sure what it means, or where should i use those `a.empty, a.bool()...` to fix it.

Comment: it is because right now, the `x` in your lambda represent a column (a series) and the operation `x > np.mean(x)+2*np.std(x)` is a series too. The problem is that using `if series` return this error. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o) for more explanation about different cases this error happens

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check row by row then you can use `np.where` instead of `if else` in your program. First parameter is your condition. When it is true it takes the second parameter at the same index. If it is wrong it takes the third parameter at the same index.

```
df.apply(lambda x:np.where(x > np.mean(x)+2*np.std(x), np.mean(x)+2*np.std(x), x), axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clip` after calculating the `mean` and `std` on whole dataframe at once.

```
df.clip(upper=df.mean()+2*df.std(), axis=1)
```

with the current input, it does not change anything, here is a way to see it:

```
# calcualte the current upper bound
_upper = df.mean() + 2*df.std()
print(_upper)
# a    5.081989
# b    6.260952
# c    3.766611
# d    4.250000
# dtype: float64

# then replace two values above the bound
df.loc[2,['a','b']] = [12,9]
print(df)
# dtype: float64
#     a  b  c  d
# 0   1  1  1  0
# 1   2  0  0  2
# 2  12  9  1  3 # see the values in column a and b
# 3   4  5  3  0

# see what clip does for the values in column a and b, index 2
print(df.clip(upper=_upper, axis=1))
#           a         b  c  d
# 0  1.000000  1.000000  1  0
# 1  2.000000  0.000000  0  2
# 2  5.081989  6.260952  1  3  # 12 and 9 replaced by the upper bound of the column
# 3  4.000000  5.000000  3  0
```